# Создание пользователей с правами

Tags: php

Добрый вечер, подскажите может есть, кусок кода. У меня уже есть регистрация пользователя, теперь хочу разграничить по правам, у одного Админ, который может добавлять новости. у другого просто просмотр страницы.

Answer (score 4):

[Управление привилегиями пользователя на основе ролей](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=37&id=1444).

> В данной статье описывается реализация доступа на основе ролей (role based access control  - RBAC). RBAC - модель системы разграничения прав доступа, в которой роли используются для выполнения различных задач, а разрешения на выполнение операций привязываются к ролям. Пользователь может получать одну или несколько ролей, которые ограничивают его полномочия на действия в системе.

Comment: ПРимерно так Я делал в своем велосипеде)

Answer (score 2):

Если только в рамках вашей задачи и вы используете реляционные БД, то:

1. Создайте таблицу **roles** (id, role, description).
2. Вставьте туда две строки: (1, 'admin', 'Администратор'), (2, 'user', 'Пользователь')
3. Создайте таблицу **users_roles** (user_id, role_id)
4. В ней соответственно следующие строки: (id_admin, 1), (id_user, 2)
5. Затем делаем SQL запрос типа:

   `SELECT role FROM roles WHERE id IN (SELECT role_id FROM users_roles WHERE user_id = '$user_id')`

Данный запрос выберет список ролей для текущего пользователя. То есть у *одного* пользователя при такой структуре может быть *много* ролей. Например, у пользователя могут быть роли: news_add, news_delete, weather_show и т.д.

Результат данного запроса лучше записать в массив `$roles = ['role1', 'role2']`, например, с помощью функции [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql_fetch_array)

Ну и наконец проверить наличие роли можно следующим способом:

```
if (in_array('admin', $roles)) {
  echo 'Im ADMIN!';
} else {
  echo 'У меня нет прав админа :(';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Реализации пока нет, но вот что для себя надумал :

Давайте придумал группы пользователей, так с моей точки зрения удобнее.

В базе данных будут таблицы :

**users_groups** / *id, name, description*

**users_groups_rules** / *id, group_id, rules*

Первая таблица нужна чисто для связки пользователя с правами его группы.

При заходе на определённую страницу мы должны знать **id** группы, в которой состоит этот пользователь. На основании данных, мы сможем отправить запрос к базе, и получить права для этой группы, типа **SELECT rules FROM users_groups_rules WHERE group_id = 'id группы пользователя'** . После получения прав этой группы мы можем разобрать их, права представляют из себя список примерно такой :

**[allow_comment;yes;]** // *разрешить добавлять комментарии? - да*

**[allow_add_news;no;]** **// разрешить добавление новостей? - нет**

Разбирается этой всё регуляркой, и возвращается в качестве массива, можно создать константы с именами **allow_comment, allow_add_news**, однако будет скушана дополнительная память.

Это примерная реализация групп пользователей, пишу свою CMS систему, придумываю способы реализации.

Comment: у Вас есть icq ?

Comment: Не пользуюсь, где-то отдельно я вам помогать не буду, т.к. знаю чем это чревато, спрашивайте здесь, ответим.

Comment: тоже раньше делал так. но когда начальник забегает и говорит: "Слушай, дружище, мы заключили с клиентом тут уникальный договор, короче, он может добавлять только новости, а удалять не может, сделаешь же, ок?" И вот после такого, когда у отдельно взятого пользователя есть разный набор прав, то группировка прав стала условной.

Comment: А вот за это спасибо, нужно будет учесть при разработке) Как вариант создавать спец группы для каждого спец пользователя, быть может от его имени будут трудиться не один, а например двое-трое?

Answer (score 0):

В одном из кейсов использования побитовых операторов в JS объяснялась система управления правами. [Почитайте](http://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators#применение-побитовых-операторов), может быть это вам поможет.